# Ошибка индексации, Python

Tags: python, индексация

Почему выдает ошибку индексации, при попытке запуска(программа для перемножения матриц). Почитал документацию, так и не понял в чем проблема
Ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\andrey\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\Matric3.py", line 26, in <module>
    C[i][j] = 0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Код:

```
def Matr(X,S,x,y):
    print('Введите элементы матрицы ',S)
    for i in range(x):
        X.append([float(input()) for j in range(y)])
    print('Матрица ', S,' = ')
    for i in range(x): # Для проверки
        for j in range(y): # как выглядит
            print(X[i][j], end=' ') # заданная матрица
        print
    return X
n = int(input('Введите N = '))
m = int(input('Введите M = '))
k = int(input('Введите K = '))
nameA = 'A'
A = []
A = Matr(A,nameA,n,m)
nameB = 'B'
B = []
B = Matr(B,nameB,m,k)
C = []
for i in range(n):
    C.append([float(0) for j in range(k)])
#print(C)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        C[i][j] = 0
        for l in range(k):
            C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][l] * B[l][j]
        print(C[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: вы делаете матрицу С размерностью n на k,  а используете n на m

Comment: В циклах `m` и `k` перепутаны.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в самом последнем, тройном цикле? Если поменять местами в нем, ответ будет неправильный и будет получаться матрица из 3 элементов(при умножении 2х1 на 1х2)

Comment: Да, в тройном цикле надо поменять m и k